# docker-machine create command hangs at waiting for an IP

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am trying to launch a docker swarm cluster. I am using ubuntu as a VM on windows 10.

When I give below command, it gets stuck while waiting for an IP.

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-no-vtx-check manager1
```

Output

```
neeraj@neeraj-VirtualBox:~$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-no-vtx-check manager1
Running pre-create checks...
(manager1) Image cache directory does not exist, creating it at /home/neeraj/.docker/machine/cache...
(manager1) No default Boot2Docker ISO found locally, downloading the latest release...
(manager1) Latest release for github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker is v18.09.1
(manager1) Downloading /home/neeraj/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso from https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v18.09.1/boot2docker.iso...
(manager1) 0%....10%....20%....30%....40%....50%....60%....70%....80%....90%....100%
Creating machine...
(manager1) Copying /home/neeraj/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso to /home/neeraj/.docker/machine/machines/manager1/boot2docker.iso...
(manager1) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(manager1) Creating SSH key...
(manager1) Starting the VM...
(manager1) Check network to re-create if needed...
(manager1) Found a new host-only adapter: "vboxnet0"
(manager1) Waiting for an IP...
```

Can someone please guide me in resolving this issue ?

Ubuntu Version - 18.04.1

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are trying to use nested virtualization (the option --virtualbox-no-vtx-check) which is not yet supported by virtualbox. The solution would be to run docker-machine directly on windows, not in ubuntu VM.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting both the .docker and .Virtualbox directories? If that doesn't work we can diagnose the problem further.

Comment: I can't find .Virtualbox directoy. Do you mean VirtualBox directory under .config ?